# Fetching CKRecordZone from a CKRecord

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Scenario:

I have a `CKRecord` which I have fetched from the server. The record exists inside a custom zone for which I do **not** know the identifier and do not have a `CKRecordZone` object for.

I need to make a call to `CKDatabase.perform(query:inZoneWith:completion:)` to get the records in the database which are components of the root shared record (which requires such a call) however without having a `CKRecordZoneID` (from a `CKRecordZone`) I am forced to iterate through every `CKRecordZone` in the shared database and perform the query until a matching record is found.

In summary: I want to take a `CKRecord` and find the `CKRecordZone` it exists in. Is this possible? **Or** is my method flawed and can I perform a `query` without the `CKRecordZoneID`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the `CKRecordZoneID` of a given record, the `recordID` property is helpful:

[`(record).recordID.zoneID`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecordid/1500969-zoneid) yields the `CKRecordZoneID` that the `CKRecord` exists in.